# THREE.js Change the opacity of an entire branch

Tags: three.js, webgl

Is there any way to change the opacity/alpha of all hierarchy (branch) rather than per each mesh material?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No. You can, however, use `object.traverse()` to set the opacity of an object's material and it's children.

```
mesh.traverse( function( node ) {
    if( node.material ) {
        node.material.opacity = 0.5;
        node.material.transparent = true;
    }
});
```

three.js r.56

Comment: Would be super great to have multiplicative opacity, so that child opacity can be relative to parent opacity, similar to how child transforms are relative to parent.