# Real group transparency in three.js

Tags: javascript, svg, three.js

Like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15214543/three-js-change-the-opacity-of-an-entire-branch), I want to change opacity of a group. But the accepted answer in that question is not completely correct. Changing opacity of a group is not equal to changing opacity of it's parts. I can show this with this small svg example:

Group opacity (Good):

```html
<svg width="200" viewBox="0 0 50 50" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g opacity="0.5">
        <g>
            <rect x="20" y="30" width="10" height="50" fill="brown"/>
            <g style="fill: #0b0">
                <circle cx="20" cy="30" r="10"/>
                <circle cx="30" cy="30" r="10"/>
                <circle cx="25" cy="20" r="10"/>
            </g>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Individual opacity (Bad):

```html
<svg width="200" viewBox="0 0 50 50" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g>
        <g>
            <rect x="20" y="30" width="10" height="50" fill="brown" opacity="0.5"/>
            <g style="fill: #0b0">
                <circle cx="20" cy="30" r="10" opacity="0.5"/>
                <circle cx="30" cy="30" r="10" opacity="0.5"/>
                <circle cx="25" cy="20" r="10" opacity="0.5"/>
            </g>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

How to do something like this in `three.js`?

Comment: @Marquizzo I have no idea about how WebGL works, If you think there is no feasible rendering strategy that solve this problem, answer this with some evidence for why is not possible.
About merging geometries, I think it isn't enough, for example I can't use it for my tree (3D kind of it) But if there is something that merge objects, and make something like a gltf file from merged objects, that would cover wide variety of use cases I think.

Comment: "answer this with some evidence for why is not possible". I don't think I have to. I was just trying to help, it's not my responsibility.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36947704/rendering-a-transparent-shell/36948438#36948438

Comment: @Marquizzo My English is bad, And I just put words in a sequence :) I mean please answer it so I can accept your answer and close the question. If I said you "have to" do this, I'm sorry. Thank you for your comment, It was helpful (Why you erase it?) even if you don't answer the question.

Comment: @hamidk Ah, I apologize. The reason I removed my first comment was because I said "It's not possible in WebGL", but WestLangley posted a link with a cool trick to solve that problem, so my statement was not true... it IS possible! :)